# Faced this error while using React-Hook-Form and YupResolver: Attempted import error: 'set' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'o')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, yup, react-hook-form

I'm developing an app using Capacitor, Ionic, React and recently I faced the following error, while using React Hook Form and YupResolver for the first time:

When I try to run the project, I get this error:

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/@hookform/resolvers/dist/resolvers.module.js
Attempted import error: 'set' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'o').
```

I want to create and validate a form for changing Password, submitting the new Password to an external API /change-password. The form will be like below:

```
Actual Password: ...
New Password: ...
Confirm new Password: ...

Submit
```

The component:

```
import {
  IonContent,
  IonPage,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
  IonButton,
  IonInput,
  IonRow,
  IonAlert,
  IonGrid,
  IonCol,
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";

 // form validation rules
  const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    password: yup
      .string()
      .min(8, "Password must be at least 8 characters")
      .required("Password is required"),
    newPassword: yup
      .string()
      .min(8, "Password must be at least 8 characters")
      .required("New Password is required"),
    confirmPassword: yup
      .string()
      .oneOf([yup.ref("newPassword"), null], "Passwords must match")
      .required("Confirm Password is required"),
  });

const ChangePassword: React.FC = () => {

//get the actual password from React Contenxt
  const {
    password,
    setPassword,
    alertMessage,
    setAlertMessage,
  } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState(""); 

  // functions to build form returned by useForm() hook
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = () => {
    const data = {
      oldPassword: password,
      newPassword: newPassword,
      sourceId: 1,
    };

    axios
      .post("change-password", data)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IonPage className="ion-page" id="main-content">
        <IonContent className="ion-padding">
          <IonGrid>  
            <h3>Change Password</h3>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel position="floating">Actual Password</IonLabel>
                <IonInput
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={password}
                  ref={register}
                  className={`form-control ${
                    errors.password ? "is-invalid" : ""
                  }`}
                  onIonChange={(e) => setPassword(e.detail.value!)}
                ></IonInput>
                <div className="invalid-feedback">
                  {errors.password?.message}
                </div>
              </IonItem>

              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel position="floating">New Password</IonLabel>
                <IonInput
                  name="newPassword"
                  type="password"
                  value={newPassword}
                  ref={register}
                  className={`form-control ${
                    errors.newPassword ? "is-invalid" : ""
                  }`}
                  onIonChange={(e) => setNewPassword(e.detail.value!)}
                ></IonInput>
                <div className="invalid-feedback">
                  {errors.newPassword?.message}
                </div>
              </IonItem>

              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel position="floating">
                  Cofirm New Password
                </IonLabel>
                <IonInput
                  name="confirmPassword"
                  type="password"
                  value={confirmPassword}
                  ref={register}
                  className={`form-control ${
                    errors.confirmPassword ? "is-invalid" : ""
                  }`}
                  onIonChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.detail.value!)}
                ></IonInput>
                <div className="invalid-feedback">
                  {errors.confirmPassword?.message}
                </div>
              </IonItem>

              <IonButton type="submit">
                Submit
              </IonButton>
            </form>
          </IonGrid>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ChangePassword;
```

```
@hookform/resolvers@2.4.0
yup@0.32.9
react-hook-form@6.15.6
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you look at [the peerDependencies](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/blob/master/package.json#L182) in the react-hook-form/resolvers repo, you need to be using react-hook-form ^7.0.0

Comment: That is not true, the working code sandbox example is not running version 7

Comment: @AaronSaunders the code in the sandbox also isn't using the same versions the OP's code is. I'm not saying you can't make it work on old versions, I'm just saying that if you're going to use @hookform/resolvers ^2.4.0, then you need to be using react-hook-form ^7.0.0

Comment: @Adam, I thought the same, I found no other way to move on so I upgraded from 6.15.6 to 7.1.1 https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/ . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a solution specifically for this error. So I decided to move on with the implementation and  upgraded RHF from 6.x.x to the last version 7.1.1, since I'm using the latest version of Resolvers too.
https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/
I also adjusted the implementation based on RHF version 7 documentation:
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform

Now it is working properly.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue when using react-hook-form v6.16.5 and @hookform/resolvers v2.5.2

I downgraded @hookform/resolvers to v1.3.7 and it works now.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This seems to be an issue of react-hook-form and resolvers version. In my case, I'm using "react-hook-form": "^7.1.1" and "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.4.0" and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

My error was that I had implemented the import as

`import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers";` instead of

`import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";`

Leaving this here as it may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

The way things are done have changed with react-hook-form. Also you don't need to track the values yourself, you can get them from react-hook-form.

This code is tested and works - See link here - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-fieldsarray-yup-validation-min-length-forked-rccmg?file=/src/index.js:0-1934

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import { object, ref, string } from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers";
// import "./styles.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/core.css";

import {
  IonContent,
  IonPage,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
  IonButton,
  IonInput
} from "@ionic/react";

const validationSchema = object().shape({
  password: string()
    .min(8, "Password must be at least 6 characters")
    .required("Password is required"),
  newPassword: string()
    .oneOf([ref("password"), null], "Passwords must match")
    .required("New Password is required"),
  confirmPassword: string()
    .oneOf([ref("newPassword"), null], "Passwords must match")
    .required("Confirm Password is required")
});

function App() {
  const { register, errors, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(console.log)}>
          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel>PASSWORD</IonLabel>
            <IonInput name="password" type="text" ref={register}></IonInput>
          </IonItem>

          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel>NEW PASSWORD</IonLabel>
            <IonInput name="newPassword" type="text" ref={register}></IonInput>
          </IonItem>

          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel>CONFIRM PASSWORD</IonLabel>
            <IonInput
              name="confirmPassword"
              type="text"
              ref={register}
            ></IonInput>
          </IonItem>

          <pre>Errors: {JSON.stringify(errors, null, 2)}</pre>
          <pre>Values: {JSON.stringify(getValues(), null, 2)}</pre>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I adjusted my code based on your code and I still get the error: Attempted import error: 'set' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'o'). I thought it might be an issue related to the react hook form version. I upgraded RHF from version 6.x.x to 7.1.1 and now I don't get this error. I still have a lot to fix in the code, but at least I don't get the error.

Comment: There must be some other error because if you look at the working codesandbox example you will see that it is running WITHOUT upgrading to version 7. I specifically tested using the version of RHF you were using abs I don’t want others who read this to believe the fix is that you have to upgrade to make it work. However I am glad you where able to move on

Comment: yes you are right, I don't want to say that upgrading RHF was the solution for this error, but since I was using the latest version of resolvers, I thought I could do the same with RHF. This was the reason why I upgraded RHF and adjusted the code based on your code and on react hook v7 documentation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using **"react-hook-form": "^7.25.1"** version and i was importing as

**import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers";**    Instaed of

you can import as shown below (it's working for me)

**import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';**