# yup conditional validation of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

I want to validate the array on the base of loan register if loan register is true then array should validate else not.

```
yup.object().shape({
                
                loan_register: yup.boolean(),
                loans: yup.array()
                    .of(
                        yup.object().shape({
                            bank_name: yup.string().required(),
                            bank_reg_no: yup.string().required(),
                            loan_amount: yup.string().required(),

                        })
                    )

            })
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `of` is not an exported member from yup is because yup needs to know the type of data first. You can only use `of` once you know the type.

For example: `array().of()`, `string().oneOf()`,  e.t.c

Hence, in your case, you need to provide the data type and it will solve your problem.

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({     
             loan_register: yup.boolean(),
             loans: yup.array().when('loan_register', {
                          is: true,
                          then: yup.array().of(
                                  yup.object({
                                      bank_name: yup.string().required(),
                                      bank_reg_no:yup.string().required(),
                                      loan_amount:yup.string().required(),
                               }))
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: '*When loan_register === true, bank_name, bank_reg_no and loan_amount must be strings and required fields.*'

You can translate that requirement into code like following (include **Yup conditional validation** using `.when()` ):

```
    const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({        
         loan_register: yup.boolean(),
         loans: yup.array()
        .when('loan_register', {
            is: true,
            then: yup.of(
                yup.object().shape({
                    bank_name: yup.string().required(),
                    bank_reg_no: yup.string().required(),
                    loan_amount: yup.string().required(),
                })
             )
        })
    })
```

Comment: It's much more helpful if you explain a bit about what you did with the code, and why.

Comment: The code explains itself. when("loan_register") is true, bank_name, bank_reg_no and loan_amount must be validated as strings and must be required.  I just added one more condition in comparison to the original question. You don't have to vote down my answer only because of this. I'm trying to help!

Comment: "While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion." -- I also didn't intend to downvote, that was a mistake on my part. If you edit your answer to include a short explanation, I think that will clear the downvote (or will allow me to clear it).

Comment: @Ani  `Attempted import error: 'of' is not exported from 'yup' (imported as 'yup').`
this error is appearing with the method you provided 
my import statement is 
` import * as yup from 'yup'`

Comment: @FaizanAhmed, have you added these imports? 
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
Also, could you please tell me the version of react-hook-form  and @hookform/resolvers ?

Comment: i havent imported yupResolver ... let me add and check...i am using formik library.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hookform/resolvers I have been using only this package. I cannot help you with Formik, but I think that's an error related to yup and react versions. Times ago, I had a similar issue and I solved it upgrading the versions. Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157493/faced-this-error-while-using-react-hook-form-and-yupresolver-attempted-import-e/67876939#67876939

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to utilize [.when()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema).  This allows exactly what you're looking for by providing conditional validation checks based off other attribute values.

It has a more explicit approach where you'd add

```js
.when('loan_register', {is: true, then: /* yup schema */ })
```

I believe the change would look like

```js
yup.object().shape({
    loan_register: yup.boolean(),
    loans: yup.array()
        .when('loan_register', {
            is: true,
            then: yup.of(
                yup.object().shape({
                    bank_name: yup.string().required(),
                    bank_reg_no: yup.string().required(),
                    loan_amount: yup.string().required(),
                })
            )
        })
})
```

Comment: `Attempted import error: 'of' is not exported from 'yup' (imported as 'yup').`
this error is appearing with the method you provided 
my import statement is ` import * as yup from 'yup'`